Getting TypeScript to infer types in dynamic dispatcher
I'm trying to build a dynamic dispatch, similar to this:
enum AnimalType {
  Rabbit = 'Rabbit',
  Duck = 'Duck',
}

interface RabbitInput {
  animalType: AnimalType.Rabbit;
  food: string;
}

interface DuckInput {
  animalType: AnimalType.Duck;
  swim_speed: number;
}

type AnimalInput = RabbitInput | DuckInput

type AnimalFunctionMap = {
  [AnimalType.Duck]: (input: DuckInput) => Promise<any>;
  [AnimalType.Rabbit]: (input: RabbitInput) => Promise<any>;
};

const eat = async (input: RabbitInput) => {
    return { 'status': 'satisfied' };
}
const swim = async(input: DuckInput) => {
    return { 'status': 'fast' };
}

const animalFunctions: AnimalFunctionMap = {
  [AnimalType.Duck]: swim,
  [AnimalType.Rabbit]: eat,
};

function isRabbitInput(input: AnimalInput): input is RabbitInput {
  return input.animalType === AnimalType.Rabbit
}
function isDuckInput(input: AnimalInput): input is DuckInput {
  return input.animalType === AnimalType.Duck
}
const applyAnimalBehaviour = async (input: AnimalInput): Promise<any> => {
  const animalFunction = animalFunctions[input.animalType];
  if (animalFunction) {
    if (isRabbitInput(input)) {
      return await animalFunction(input); 
    } else if (isDuckInput(input)) {
      return await animalFunction(input);
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported animal type.`);
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error(`No animal function found for type.`);
  }
};

For reasons I don't understand, this yields:
Argument of type 'DuckInput' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'DuckInput & RabbitInput' was reduced to 'never' because property 'animalType' has conflicting types in some constituents.(2345)

I would have thought that I could get TS to infer that the types of the applyAnimalBehaviour parameters would be matched to an appropriate function, even without the type guards. But I can't make it work.

This is ms/TS#30581 and the recommended approach is a generic refactoring as given in ms/TS#47109.  For your example that looks like this playground link code. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

This looks fantastic, I've adapted it back to my original code and it now compiles just fine. I would be glad to see this as an answer with some explanations as well. :)

TypeScript is unable to deal with correlated union types as described in microsoft/TypeScript#30581.  You're hoping that you can mention input twice in code like animalFunctions[input.animalType](input) and have TypeScript realize that it is either a RabbitInput both times or a DuckInput both times, and that either way, the function call should be allowed.
But TypeScript ends up treating both utterances of input as independent values of type AnimalInput.  As if you wrote animalFunctions[input1.animalType](input2). Which of course wouldn't be safe, because... what if input1 is a RabbitInput and input2 is a DuckInput or vice versa?  Of course we know that's impossible, but TypeScript currently lacks the machinery to track the identity of input here. It's just looking at the type. So animalFunctions[input.animalType] is a union of functions. And the only safe way to call a union of functions with input as an argument would be if input had all possible input types. That is, the intersection type RabbitInput & DuckInput. But it's not, and you get an error.

The recommended approach to dealing with correlated unions is to refactor to use generics as described in microsoft/TypeScript#47109. The idea is that you want to write everything in terms of:

a base key-value mapping interface, or
mapped types over that mapping interface, or
generic indexes into those types.

We want input.animalType to be a generic type, and for all utterances of input to be generic in such a way as to cause animalFunctions[input.animalType] to be seen as a single function type, not a union of functions, and for its parameter type to be seen as the same as the type of input.
Here's one way to do it:
interface AnimalMap {
    [AnimalType.Rabbit]: { food: string }
    [AnimalType.Duck]: { swim_speed: number };
}

type AnimalInput<K extends AnimalType = AnimalType> = { [P in K]:
    { animalType: P } & AnimalMap[P]
}[K]

type AnimalFunctionMap = { [K in AnimalType]: (input: AnimalInput<K>) => Promise<any> }

const animalFunctions: AnimalFunctionMap = {
    [AnimalType.Rabbit]: async (input) => {
        return { 'status': 'satisfied' };
    },
    [AnimalType.Duck]: async (input) => {
        return { 'status': 'fast' };
    }
};

const applyAnimalBehaviour = async <K extends AnimalType>(
    input: AnimalInput<K>
): Promise<any> => {
    const animalFunction = animalFunctions[input.animalType];
    return await (animalFunction(input));
};

The base type AnimalMap represents the mapping between the animal type and the input. We've made AnimalInput generic in K extends AnimalType. It's a distributive object type, so that AnimalInput<AnimalType.Rabbit> is equivalent to your RabbitInput and so that AnimalInput<AnimalType.Duck> is equivalent to your DuckInput. And AnimalInput<AnimalType> (where AnimalType is just the union AnimalType.Rabbit | AnimalType.Duck) is equivalent to the union type RabbitInput | DuckInput.  I've given it the default generic type argument AnimalType so when you write just AnimalInput, it's equivalent to your original type.
But importantly, the animalType property of AnimalInput<K> is explicitly written in terms of K, so TypeScript can see that AnimalInput<K> has an animalType of type K. It doesn't need to try to deduce it from inspecting the different animalType properties of separately defined input types (which it can't do).
The AnimalFunctionMap type is equivalent to your version, but it is again explicitly written in terms of K, so TypeScript knows that an AnimalFunctionMap[K] is a function that accepts an AnimalInput<K>.
And finally applyAnimalBehaviour() is also generic in K extends AnimalType, and the implementation is simple enough. Since input is of type AnimalInput<K>, then TypeScript knows input.animalType is of type K. So animalFunctions[input.animalType] is of type (input: AnimalInput<K>) => Promise<any>.  And so it accepts an argument of type AnimalInput<K>, and that's input.
Playground link to code
